# How to create an arrayList of objects from xml?

Tags: java, xml, object, arraylist

I have an xml file, with the following structure:

```
 <elements number="3">
     <contact>
       <name>PAUL</name>
       <surname>ONE</surname>
       <code>A1</code>
       <city>NEWYORK</city>
     </contact>
     <contact>
       <name>LAURA</name>
       <surname>TWO</surname>
       <code>A2</code>
       <city>WASHINGTON</city>
     </contact>
     <contact>
       <name>JOHN</name>
       <surname>THREE</surname>
       <code>A3</code>
       <city>BOSTON</city>
     </contact>
```

I also have a class `Contact`, with the attributes `name`, `surname`, `code` and `city`. I am trying to create an arrayList of objects `Contact` from the .xml file.
My solution would be so:

```
private String inputContacts ="inputContacts.xml";

public ArrayList<Contact> readContacts() {
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        int k = 0;
        try {
            xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            xmlr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(inputContacts, new FileInputStream(inputContacts)); 

            while (xmlr.hasNext()) {
                 switch (xmlr.getEventType()) {
                 case XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT: 
                     System.out.println("Start Read Doc " + inputContacts); 
                     break;

                 case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: 
                    switch (xmlr.getLocalName()) {
                    case "contact":
                         System.out.println("Tag " + xmlr.getLocalName());
                         Contact p = new Contact();
                         contacts.add(p);
                         k++;
                        break;

                    case "name":
                        contacts.get(k).setName(xmlr.getText());
                        break;

                    case "surname":
                        contacts.get(k).setSurname(xmlr.getText());
                        break;

                    case "code":
                        contacts.get(k).setCode(xmlr.getText());
                        break;

                    case "city":
                        contacts.get(k).setCity(xmlr.getText());
                        break;

                    default:
                        break; 
                     }

                     break;
                 case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT: 
                     System.out.println("END-Tag " + xmlr.getLocalName()); 

                     break;
                 case XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT:
                    System.out.println("// comment " + xmlr.getText()); 
                     break;
                 case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS: 

                     break;

                 }

                xmlr.next();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Reader initialization error:");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
            }

        return contacts;
        }
```

The problem is that is starts reading the file, but immediately after having entered in the document, it return everything equals to `null`.

Thanks in advance to everybody!

Comment: You set k=0 in the beginning, and then increment it after adding a new element, and then try to address this element by k, which is equal to 1 at this point. But arrays are indexed from 0, so you should get IndexOutOfBoundsException. Try to set k=-1 initially.

Comment: It doesn’t work

Comment: right, you need to use xmlr.getElementText() vs getText()

Comment: @Egor it was soo simple. Thanks! That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAXB library for this purpose. For example:

Create root class with list of contacts:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "elements")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ContactsList {
    @XmlElement(name = "contact")
    private List<Contact> list;
}
```

and class which represents Contact data:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "contact")
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String surname;   
    private String code;   
    private String city;
}
```

and then using `Unmarshaller` read your .xml file e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        File file = new File("your-file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ContactsList.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        ContactsList contacts = (ContactsList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        for (Contact c: contacts.getList()) {
            System.out.println(c.toString());
        }
}
```

Comment: Isn’t there a way without external libraries,  but the one I already included?